# iOS app for iPad I (and iOS 5.1.1)

Tags: ios

We are making an iOS iPad app, that needs to work on iPads 1, which means that it has to work on iOS 5.1.1 as this is the latest iOS version supported on them.

1. Does this mean that the target for this app needs to be 5.1.1?
2. Is there a way to install iOS 5.1.1 simulator into Xcode so far I have only been able to add 5.1.
3. Are there any 'tricks' that need to be done to get Xcode 4.5.2 to prepare iOS 5.1.1 apps?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, but it can be as low as you want it to be (target iOS 4.3 for all Xcode cares).
2. No, iOS 5.1.1 was not released as a new simulator (bug fix builds are rarely sent out to developers as new simulators).
3. Just link to the highest possible SDK and set the deployment target correctly, and you should be fine.

Comment: Thanks, for #3, what do you mean. 
What should I link as highest possible SDK?
And do you mean 5.1.1 or 6.*?
And what to should I set the deployment target?
Thanks again

Comment: @MassiveBoisson You can link to any SDK you want, however it is recommended that you link to the latest (6.0).  It's a little counterintuitive, but if you link to the latest and set your deployment target lower than latest, it's perfectly valid.